# iOS: RTSP Stream in background

Tags: ios, video, vlc, rtsp, libvlc

I'm developing an iOS app to play a RTSP Stream (with two tracks, one audio and one for video), and i'm using libVLC to do it.

Playing the video or only audio (adding the option "--no-video") works perfectly. If i start the player with only audio and then enter background the player keeps playing the stream.
The problem i'm having is that if i enter background when video is playing, i want to stop the video and start a new libVLC player with only audio. In that scenario i get this error message:

> ERROR: [0x48e2000] >aurioc> 783: failed: '!int' (enable 2, outf< 2 ch, 48000 Hz, Float32, inter> inf< 2 ch, 0 Hz, Float32, non-inter>)
>
> [1973b5e4] audiounit_ios audio output error: failed to init AudioUnit (560557684)
>
> [1973b5e4] audiounit_ios audio output error: opening AudioUnit output failed
>
> [1973b5e4] core audio output error: module not functional
>
> [17a27e74] core decoder error: failed to create audio output

The code in my appDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{   
    NSLog(@"applicationDidEnterBackground");
    if(_playerController!=NULL){
        [_playerController performSelector:@selector(goToBackground) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

        _playerController=NULL;
    }
}
```

And in my uiViewController:

```
-(void)close:(BOOL)enterBackground
{
    [_mediaPlayer stop];

    NSArray* options   = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--no-video"]];
    _mediaPlayer = [[VLCMediaPlayer alloc] initWithOptions:options];
    _mediaPlayer.delegate = self;
    _mediaPlayer.drawable = _videoView;
    _mediaPlayer.media = [VLCMedia mediaWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];   
    [_mediaPlayer play];
}
```

Am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

yes, don't stop the video and start a new player. Just disable video decoding on the existing player and re-enable it once your app is in the foreground again. This is way more efficient, elegant and faster. Additionally, you won't run into this audio session locking issue.

How is VLC for iOS doing this? When the app is on the way to the background, we store the current video track's ID, which can be "1" but also something entirely else depending on the played stream, in a variable next to the media player object. Then, we we switch the media player's video track to "-1", which is the value for "off" in any case. Video decoding stops. Once the app moves to the foreground again, the media player's video track is set to the cached track ID again and video decoding starts again.